# When installing a gem, should only the library get installed, or should the executable get installed as well?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

I have installed RSpec with the gem (gem install rspec) command. Everything went ok. If I try to reinstall it again, I get a message like it has already been installed.

When I try to use rspec from the command line on Ubuntu, the terminal can't find the program.

My question is does the gem command only install the libraries, meaning I need to manually install the rspec executable myself, or is the gem command supposed to install everything, which would mean something went wrong during the install?

Comment: I think the executable should have been installed. Check that the rspec executable is on your PATH.

Comment: Isn't there a Ubuntu package for this? On Debian, there is a ruby-rspec deb package. I know that one is supposed to use gem intall, but I found packages really helpful when installing things with additional dependencies like ruby-gtk and ruby-gsl.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky : Yes there is an Ubuntu package and I could install it. Although I could use it, I would rather like to know if gem install is supposed to take care of this so I could then try and work out what went wrong. Of course if everything fails I will use the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that the executable does get installed and should be able to run on it's own.

You can verify that the gem is installed by checking the list of installed gem using : gem query.

You can also check the paths used by gem using: gem env.

This should give you the path to the Ruby version the gems are using, their executable path (so you can update your path) and where they are stored.

Make sure they are configured to use the correct Ruby version (if you use more than one) and the path is in you $PATH variable.